# validation for drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

i have a drop down menu for country
`<g:select class="ddlCountry" id="country" name="country.id"
                                from="${Country.list()}"
                                noSelection="['':'-Select-']" optionKey="id" required="" 
                                value="${countryInstance?.id}" class="many-to-one" />`

and a submit button as follows

```
<button class="submit_small" >
                                <g:link class="ggg" controller="country" action="wholeTestUnits"
                                    id="${countryInstance?.id}">
                                    <g:message code="default.button.addTest.label" />
                                </g:link>
                                </button>
```

i want to disable the button when null option or selected index is 0 and want to enable when index increased

i have tried a javascript function as follows but it doesn't work because the button consist of  tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('button.submit_small').attr('disabled','disabled');
         $('#country').change(function() {
            if($(this).val() != '') {
               $('button[class="submit_small"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
         });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable your link in addition to button.

This code should work:

```
$(function() {
    var button = $('.submit_small').prop('disabled', true),
        link = button.find('a');

    $('#country').on('change', function(event) {
        if (event.currentTarget.value != '') {
            button.prop('disabled', false);
            link.off('.quiz');
        }
    });

    link.on('click.quiz', function(event) {
        if (button.prop('disabled')) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ant_Ti/hYNxs/

Comment: fantastic it works fine thank you, thank you so much, could you refer me any javascript book or link for learning thank you

Comment: @John l'll try to find some suitable books, but i'm afraid you won't find answer to your question just in one book... maybe this section will help find information you interested in http://www.quora.com/JavaScript

Comment: @John I need a help from you for enabling and disabling td in a table please see my following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909673/javascript-for-enable-and-dissable-td-in-table....... I hope you will surely help me